# why is LaTeX / pdflatex compiler so 'funky' with multiple compiles necessary and bogus error messages, etc, compared to c++?

Tags: pdf, compiler-construction, latex, compiler-errors, pdf-generation

Is there a simple explanation for why the latex / pdflatex compiler is funky in the following two ways:

1) N multiple compiles are necessary until you reach a "steady state" version. N seems to grow up to around 5 or 6 if I use many packages and references.

2) Error messages are almost always worthless. The actual error is not flagged. Example:

```
  \begin{itemize} % Line 499
   \begin{enumerate}
    % Comment: error: forgot to close the enumerate block 
    \item This is a bullet point. 
  \end{itemize}   % Line 503
```

result:  "Error on line 1 while scanning \begin{document}", not very useful.

I realize there is a separate "tex exchange" but I'm wondering if someone knowledgeable about c++, java, or other compilers can provide some insight on how those seem to support single-compile and proper error localization.

Edit: this document seems like a rant justifying the hacks in latex's implementation, but what about latex's syntax/language properties make the weird implementation necessary?   http://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf

Comment: I know the multiple compiles is necessary because of the ability to label equations, pages, etc within the markup and reference them later. The document has to be compiled once to (e.g.) number all the equations, and then again to substitute these numbers into the references.

Comment: It's a good question. Considering Don Knuth invented LR(1) parsing ...

Comment: Lots of compilers make multiple passes through their sources.  Not all of them make this obvious.

Comment: You shouldn't compare LaTeX or other document compiler with a software compiler. Their tasks a very different. LaTeX writes certain informations like the values and positions of labels in the first run, then includes them in the second. The table of contents is produced by writing all the information from the sectioning macros in a `.toc` file which is then included in the next run. Without the multiple runs LaTeX would have to buffer the whole document in order to include the TOC at the beginning with informations just provided at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a LaTeX point of view:

1. You should at most require 3 (...maybe 4) to reach a steady state. This depends not on the number of packages, but possible layout changes within your document. Layout changes cause references to move, and these references need to be correct (hence the recompile until they don't move).
2. Nesting of environments is allowed (although this does not address your problem directly). Also, macro definitions act as replacement text for your input. So, even though you write `\end{itemize}`, it is actually transformed into a bunch of other/different (primitive) macros, removing the obvious-to-humans structure and consequently also the bizarre error message. That's why some of the error messages are difficult to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

wrt. point (2):
Considering that most of the errors are picked up while parsing macro defenitions that get expanded, My guess is that errors wouldn't be useful to the user even if they contained locale and specific causes, because they don't translate well into what you see when you view the code.

Still, it would be useful if they were just a little bit more explicit :/

Comment: Ah, didn't read the other answer, seems like I just repeated what was already said